# Dynamically mount angular 2 directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

### Context

I have a simple directive that add some attributes to a given HTML element based on received attributes.

```
<button class="btn btn-blue x-large" [myDirective]="{ some_json_data: true }">
    Unfold
</button>
```

The `myDirective` directive just does some logic in the `ngOnInit` hook and decorates the `ElementRef` native element (in this case the button) adding attributes, nothing complicated.

```typsecript
ngOnInit(): void {
  const el: Element = this.element.nativeElement;
  this.decorate(el, this.myDirective);
}
```

### Problem

Based on a given logic (in `myDirective` decoration) I want to add a tooltip (which is another directive) to the element referenced by `ElementRef` at `myDirective`.

**How do I mount a directive manually and how do I add it to an element (ViewContainerRef)?**

Comment: you can't add directives to the html after it was compiled, read [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)

Answer (score 2):

Adding or removing directives dynamically is not supported. Only components can be added and removed dynamically (only dynamically added components can be removed dynamically).

Comment: Bounty asks for credible sources: [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8785) I think is relevant

Answer (score 2):

You do not add or remove directives dynamically, but if you want to add a tooltip 
you have to insert a div in your component template that activates it depending on a variable status

```html
<div [hidden]="tooltipnotshown"
     class="tooltip">
 blah blah or whatever ...
</div>
```