# Add directive only if condition is true

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have a directive that I want to add to div but only if the user is on a particular page. The code below shows the directive but I want it to be only added if that page is as follows in the second snippet - I have the variable `selectedSection` that will provide me with page the user is on

// my html code

`<div class="dynamic-tabs" prompt="manage">`

// my pseudocode

`if (selectedSection == 'admin') then add the 'prompt="manage" directive`

Comment: Note: that dupe link was the ___first___ google search result, from searching the exact title of this question. Zabs, please do your research before asking.

Comment: I think he is asking for angular not angularjs. it looks like you marked duplicate with the link to angularjs. note that angular and angularjs are two entirely different framework

Comment: Note: the second dupe link was the _first_ google search result, from searching the exact title of this question + "2". Zabs, please do your research before asking.

Comment: @AniruddhaDas: The same comment still applies. Search before asking.

Comment: Rather a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45084292/dynamically-mount-angular-2-directive/45324407#45324407 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021355/angular-2-how-to-conditionally-apply-attribute-directive/37022051#37022051

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: Feel free to add the links.

Comment: @Cerbrus can you please reopen, this is Angular 2 and the other is Angular JS. I don't know if I can reopen **and** mark as duplicate (AFAIK there is a limitation).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: You have a gold badge in some of the tags here, you should be able to just change the links (Bottom-right of the yellow "duplicate" block)

Comment: @Cerbrus thanks a lot! Never noticed before that I can edit there :D

Comment: @Cerbrus, I think the angularjs link need to be removed. the user will confused with angular.

Answer (score 0):

What about an *ngIf condition? (or ng-if with Angular 1)

```
<div class="dynamic-tabs" prompt="manage" *ngIf="selectedSection === 'admin'"> </div>

<div class="dynamic-tabs" *ngIf="selectedSection !== 'admin'"> </div>
```