# Angular - Append dropdown to div

Tags: angular, typescript, appendchild, elementref

I am trying to add dropdown to a div. The html code (dropdown is an example) is dynamic code. Even though on clicking it shows the dropdown button but the dropdown isn't working. Following is my code from component file

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@ViewChild('showfilters') el:ElementRef;


this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML + `
<div class="dropdown " dropdown>
   <a class="dropdown-toggle  text-light" dropdownToggle> New Dropdown</a>
   <div class="dropdown-menu mt-2 mr-3" *dropdownMenu>
     <a class="dropdown-item"> Profile</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
     <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
       <a class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>New</a>
   </div>
</div>
`;
```

My html
    `<div class="showfilters" #showfilters>`

I have created an example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-dropdown-angular-pymcab?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) too.

Comment: your problem is add dynamic directive to div https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45084292/dynamically-mount-angular-2-directive

Comment: So based on the answer in the link I cant add dropdown dynamically?

Comment: You can... it's just not as simple as appending HTML to the document (which is never a good idea in angular anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend not adding HTML to your component this way, instead you could just use `*ngFor` with a small hack.

Forked: https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-dropdown-angular-xcg7xf

The hack... `*ngFor="let dummy of ' '.repeat(dropDownCount).split('')"`

basically creates an array that has the exact length of your variable so that `*ngFor` can iterate through it.

If you insist on having to add HTML through your component, you may have to take a look at this: [Equivalent of $compile in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2)

Comment: thank you for your kind response. Kindly note the html code is dynamic. I doubt it will work with dynamic.

Comment: Then this question might be a duplicate of the linked Question.